# printf cannot print float/double correctly on the screen

Tags: c, operating-system, embedded, printf, mips

Recently, I'm working with a special embedded operating system running on the [MIPS](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/MIPS_architecture) architecture. I do not know much about it. When I use the printf function, see some strange things:

```
int a = 10;
float b = 3.14;
double c = 3.14;

printf("a is %d\n", a);           // I'm sorry I forgot to type the parameters just now
printf("b is %f\n", b);           //  Error
printf("c is %f\n", c);           //  Error
```

The output is:

```
a is 10
b is 0.000000
```

`a` is right, but `b` seems to be wrong, and `c` even can not be printed. Function printf comes from newlib (a C language library). Be careful, the float/double numbers can be calculated correctly, stored correctly in the memory, and they just can not be printed correctly.

I think there maybe something wrong with the operating system. I just wonder what could be the reason. Is there anyone who has met this problem before?

Comment: Instead of blaming the OS, how about showing a minimal, complete, compilable example ([SSCCE](http://sscce.org))?

Comment: Can you please show the actual code?

Comment: Perhaps pass those parameters to the `printf()` function? Even better, [read the documentiation](http://en.cppreference.com/w/c/io/fprintf).

Comment: I could bet anything that `a is 10` is not printed. More likely `a is 0`, cause you forgot to pass the parameters to `printf`.

Comment: What's the OS? What's the compiler?

Comment: The OS is based on Rtems, but someone has changed some code, I don't know exactly the changes. The compiler is gcc(mips  architecture).

Comment: No problem with this code. See the [output](http://ideone.com/yWcsZS).
I think either it is compiler issue or your IDE is not working properly.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The MIPS-EABI requires 8-byte stack alignment and your "special embedded operating system" is aligning the stack on 4-byte boundaries.

An application that appears to function correctly until a double is passed as a function argument is a typical symptom of this error.

You need to ensure that the operating system creates threads with 8-byte stack alignment.

Comment: The normal `O32` MIPS calling convention requires a 4 byte stack alignment.

Comment: @markgz According to the *DEFAULT C CALLING CONVENTION (O32)* section of the [MIPS32 Instruction Set Quick Reference](http://www.mips.com/media/files/MD00565-2B-MIPS32-QRC-01.01.pdf): "The stack must be 8-byte aligned."

Comment: @DKrueger - +1 this is potentially insightful and may well be the answer, however a calling convention is only a contract between pieces of software, none of which are necessarily involved here.  Can you demonstrate that the 8 byte alignment reflects a *hardware requirement* or that the printf implementation in use adheres to MIPS-EABI or the O32 calling convention, vs being part of a system which does its own non-standard thing with the MIPS processor?

Comment: @DKrueger: you are right about the alignment, and Wikipedia is confused (no surprise :-)

Comment: thanks you have saved me a lot. I just note that same is applicable to Keil ARM M0+ compiler and using CMSIS-RTOS

Answer (score 3):

Are you sure that float and double support is enabled for input/output functions like printf() in your build of the newlib library?
Maybe your newlib has been compiled with the options

> --disable-newlib-io-float 
>   --disable-newlib-io-long-double

Default is "enabled".

[Edit]

In the embedded world many applications do not need float/double operations. But supporting float/double in the libs requires a significant amount of memory which is often a rare resource. So it is a common practice to disable support of float/double in the stdio lib if it is not required. In IDEs these stdio libs without support of float/double are typically called "tiny" or "small". Please check if you link against such a "tiny" version of your newlib. 
I have the strong suspicion that this the reason for your problems.

Comment: Yes,this is one of the reasons,but when I compiled the newlib I do not  give these two options.So there must be other reasons. Thanks to give one possible answer.

Comment: @Shadowxiaoh: Not very likely in this case but maybe worth to try: Does "errno" show an error code (errno != 0)?

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem with printf("%f", some_double) on Newlib with ARM.
The solution:
Declare your stack as

```
unsigned long long myStackRegion[MY_STACK_SIZE / sizeof(unsigned long long)];
```

For MIPS, you should verify that sizeof(unsigned long long) == 8.